# call custom action after delete account

Tags: actions, buddypress

I want to call custom action, after a user is deleting his account. I'm using the premium theme wplms which is using buddypress for this stuff. After the submit button in the **delete-account.php** there is called the action *bp_members_delete_account_after_submit*:

```
               //...
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Konto löschen" id="delete-account-button" name="delete-account-button" />
        </div>

    <?php do_action( 'bp_members_delete_account_after_submit' ); ?>
```

According to this http://hookr.io/actions/bp_members_delete_account_after_submit/ I implemented the following code in my **function.php**:

```
function action_bp_members_delete_account_after_submit(  ) {
  do_action('myAction', 'arg1', 'arg2');
};
add_action( 'bp_members_delete_account_after_submit', 'action_bp_members_delete_account_after_submit', 10, 0 );
```

But nothing is happening. It seems like this function will never called? Did I something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the function `myAction()` is doing.

Your order is this:

1. pluging defines action hook with `do_action( 'bp_members_delete_account_after_submit' );`
2. You hook a function on that with

   ```
   add_action( 'bp_members_delete_account_after_submit',
               'action_bp_members_delete_account_after_submit' );
   ```
3. the function `action_bp_members_delete_account_after_submit()` is then adding a hook named `'myAction'` and passing it two arguments as strings `'arg1'` and `'arg2'`.

But there is nothing to *"happen"* in the code above, unless you have a function hooked to `myAction`.

```
add_action( 'myAction', 'my_function', 10, 2 );

function my_function( $first_arg, $second_arg ) {
     //here, $first_arg would be literally equal to text 'arg1'
     // $second_arg would be literally equal to the text 'arg2'

     //you would do stuff here
}
```

---

Of course, you could skip some of that and run the code you need run inside the `action_bp_members_delete_account_after_submit()` function by making it:

```
function action_bp_members_delete_account_after_submit() {
    //you would do stuff here, 
    //no need to make another hook if you are not going to hook things to it
}
```